# How to link a href to new page /curentpage/newpage

Tags: php, html, href

How to link a href to new page `/curentpage/newpage`

Like - I want to make `<a href="/newpage">`
and when i click it it will go to `/currentpage/newpage`
not to `www.example.com/newpage`

Comment: What is the URL of the current page?  Does it have a trailing slash?  Is it `/currentpage` or is it `/currentpage/`?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the current page URL.

```
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
         $url = "https://";   
    else  
         $url = "http://";   
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];       
    $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then you will concatenate new link with this url like this.

```
$url = $url.'/newpage';
```

Then you can add this url to href like this.

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">link</a>
```

Comment: Why are you including the protocol and http host in the link?   A root relative link to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/newpage'` I'd think would be enough.

Comment: yes, right you can do that, but I tried it to be more perfect